# What's the most straightforward way in PHP to create an associative array from two parallel indexed arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

Given the following two indexed arrays:

```
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$b = array('red', 'blue', 'green');
```

What is the most straighforward/efficient way to produce the following associative array?:

```
$result_i_want = array('a' => 'red', 'b' => 'blue', 'c' => 'green');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine)

In your case:

```
$result_i_want = array_combine($a, $b);
```

Comment: Learn something new every day. I've done PHP for six years and never heard of that function.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$b = array('red', 'blue', 'green');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);
print_r($c);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [a] => red
    [b] => blue
    [c] => green
)
```