# Turn indexed array to associative array

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the most straightforward way in PHP to create an associative array from two parallel indexed arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000330/whats-the-most-straightforward-way-in-php-to-create-an-associative-array-from-t)

How to convert indexed array like:

```
$a = array("foo", "bar", "hallo", "world");
```

to associative array with values from indexed one like:

```
$a = array(
    "a1" => "foo",
    "b5" => "bar",
    "f7" => "hallo",
    "n4" => "world"
);
```

Maybe some PHP core function?

Or a variant with the same `keys` like:

```
$a = array(
    "key" => "foo",
    "key" => "bar",
    "key" => "hallo",
    "key" => "world"
);
```

**UPD**

I'd like there would be a function like `array_merge()`, but accept array of keys and array of values to create result array from.

Comment: Do you want the names of the indexes follow a particular pattern?

Comment: My second example with same `keys` is preferable.

Comment: associative array with multiple identical keys is not possible, and makes no sense

Answer (score 16):

```
$keys = array('a1', 'b5', 'f7', 'n4');
$a = array_combine($keys, $a);
```

array index must be unique, so with same keys is impossible.

Comment: Surely there must be a duplicate question for this.

Comment: Oh, yes! Havent even saw this method in DOCS. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This provides an easy way to convert an indexed array to associative with keys that reflect values: `$array = array_combine($array, $array)`…please don't ask why I needed such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

if the key is random, then we can do like this:

```
$a = array("foo", "bar", "hallo", "world");

$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$size = strlen( $chars );   
$num="0123456789";

$a_s=array();

foreach($a as $art)
{
    $rand= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ].$num[ rand( 0, 9 ) ];

    $a_s[$rand]=$art;
}

$a=$a_s;
print_r($a);
```